# Can you run node server without sudo and still connect to MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, root, sudo

(AWS UBUNTU EC2)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
According to the documentation on installing and running MongoDB, you run:
 `sudo service mongod start`
But doesn't that run the process as Root so running:
`node server`
wouldn't be able to connect to Mongo.
(I've been warned about running express server as root)
...
Using
`const connect_mongo = require('connect-mongo')(session);`

Comment: Yes, you can start mongo manually as non-privileged user `mongod --fork`. You should have access to the directories configured in mongo. It has nothing to do with nodejs server tho. Both lives independently and communicate via port 27017 by default.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me.